# Creating Word file in PHP

Tags: php, ms-word

I am trying to generate a letter written on word file using php.
So I tried the following code.

```
mysql_connect("*****","****","****") or die("error");
mysql_select_db ("sampledb") OR DIE ("Unable to select db".mysql_error());

$query1 = "select * from table ";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die (mysql_error());

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=exports22.doc");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

$k = 0;

$csvHandler = fopen("php://output", 'w');

$cars1=array("<table style='width:900px;'>
<tr><td>To</td></tr>
<tr><td style='font-size:100%;font-weight:bold;'>The Manager,</td></tr>
<tr><td >xyz ltd</td></tr>
<tr><td >Dear Sir / Madam,</td></tr>
<tr><td >&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td style='font-size:100%;font-weight:bold;'>Sub : sample subject</td></tr>
<tr><td >&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
<table style='width:900px;' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr><th>SR. NO.</th><th>ITEM NAME</th><th>QUANTITY</th><th>AMOUNT(Rs.)</th></tr>
</table>
");

fputcsv($csvHandler, $cars1);

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $k++;

    $query11 = "select * from employee where itemId = '".$rows['itemId']."' ";
    $result11 = mysql_query($query11) or die (mysql_error());
    $rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($result11);
    $ename = $rows1['itemName'];
    $acno = $rows1['Number'];
    $no = $rows1['total'];

    $rws="<table style='width:900px;' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
    <tr><td>$k</td><td>$ename</td><td>$acno</td><td>$no</td></tr>
    </table>";

    $cars=array($rws);
    fputcsv($csvHandler, $cars);
}
```

But after each table it is writing `" "`. How do I remove these unwanted chars?

Comment: Are there perhaps white spaces in the strings or in the php source file outside the `<? ... ?>`?

Comment: No, i checked it there is not blank space

Comment: What are the line breaks like? Are there `\n` and `\r` or even mixed up ones?

Comment: Why do you use putcsv at all? Do you want to write a csv file, a html file or a csv file containing (multiline) html?

Comment: first i i tried to create csv file with multiline html,then i changed to word.but my aim is same, to write multi line html

Comment: Then you might consider using `fputs` instead of `fputcsv`, right?

Comment: yes, i did notice that.